# Just realized IEnumerable<T> is immutable, what are other most commonly used immutable generic interfaces? MSDN doesn't say

Tags: c#, immutability

Just realized IEnumerable is immutable, what are other commonly used immutable generic interfaces? MSDN doesn't say.

Or any good online resources?

Comment: Is that a useful thing to know there are probably loads that you will never use, isn't that a bit like asking "is there a list of classes implement `IEnumerable<T>`"

Comment: How would you know that an implementation of IEnumerable<T> is immutable? Immutability is not part of the definition.

Answer (score 3):

Apart from the fact that it doesn't make a whole lot of sense to refer to interfaces as being [immutable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object), `IEnumerable<T>` isn't, for example:

```
List<string> myList = new List<string>();
myList.Add("Test"); // We just changed the state of myList, hence its not immutable
```

An example of an object that **is** immutable is [`String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx).

It doesn't make sense for an interface to be immutable as almost by definition an immutable object needs to be [sealed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/88c54tsw%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), which an interface obviously cannot be.

Comment: but `IEnumerable<string> myList = new List<string>(); myList.Add("Test");` is an error... because `IEnumerable<string>` is immutable.